# Python: Sorting a Python list to show which string is most common to least common and the number of times it appears

Tags: python

I have a winners list which will receive different entries each time the rest of my code is ran:

eg the list could look like:

```
winners = ['Tortoise','Tortoise','Hare']
```

I am able to find the most common entry by using:

```
mostWins = [word for word, word_count in Counter(winners).most_common(Animalnum)]
```

which would ouput:

```
['Tortoise']
```

My problem is displaying the entire list from most common to least common and the how many times each string is found in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over that `.most_common`:

```
>>> winners = ['Tortoise','Tortoise','Hare','Tortoise','Hare','Bob']
>>> import collections
>>> for name, wins in collections.Counter(winners).most_common():
...   print(name, wins)
...
Tortoise 3
Hare 2
Bob 1
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Counter is just a dictionary internally.

```py
from collections import Counter
winners = ['Tortoise','Tortoise','Hare','Tortoise','Hare','Bob', 'Bob', 'John']
counts = Counter(winners)
print(counts)
# Counter({'Tortoise': 3, 'Hare': 2, 'Bob': 2, 'John': 1})
print(counts['Hare'])
# 2
```

Furthermore, the `.most_common(n)` method is just a `.items()` call on it that limits the output to `n` length.
So you should only use it, if you'd like to show the top `n`, e.g.: the top 3

```py
counts.most_common(3)
# [('Tortoise', 3), ('Hare', 2), ('Bob', 2)]
```